# Nimbus look and feel jar file not found

Tags: jar

I have googled for two hours ,but unable to find nimbus look and feel jar. I am using jdk6 version ,need to add this library to my project..please provide useful links to download nimbus jar file

Regards
Krishnareddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, binaries and maven dependency:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.nimbus/nimbus ,also:

http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=nimbus